# How long was my flight delayed

Tags: delays

What was the take off time of west jet flight number ws2 on June 23 2016 from Gatwick airport. I want to claim compensation and can't remember what time we departed.

Answer (score 2):

According to [FlightAware](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/WJA2/history/20160623/0955Z/EGKK/CYYC), the flight departed at 2:44PM and arrived at 4:31PM. It was scheduled to depart at 10:55AM and land at 10:31AM.